# SignalR send same message in different language

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I m trying to learn and integrate SignalR in my system. I have one question here.
Assuming I have hub created and user who all are connected in this hub belongs to different locales, I have exact information of each users' locale. But while sending notification or messages how can I send the messages in their respective locales.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it , is for each local have a SignalR group , and when a client connects to your hub depending on the local register that client on the relevant group.

It will look similar to this :

Client A connects:

> Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "English");

Client B connects:

> Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "German");

Send message to clients in diffrent local :

> Clients.Group("English").SendMessage("English message");
>
> Clients.Group("German").SendMessage("German message");